# Inserting elements in a linked list of linked list

Tags: c

I have the following structures:

```
typedef struct trans {
    int code;
    int issuersAccsID;
    double amount;
    int type;
    char date [100];
    int secondPartysId;
    char description [41];
    trans *next;
} transaction;


typedef struct acct{
    int id;
    char bank [50];
    int type;
    double balance;
    acct *next;
    transaction *tnext;
} account;


struct client{
    int id;
    char name [150];
    char city [200];
    char phone [30];
    client *next;
    account *anext;
};
```

When I insert elements in the list "clients" it's working fine, but the problem is when I go to the "sublist", because it inserts the last element infinitely.

```
void fileExists(client **p){
    client *ax = new client, *t = *p;
    scanf("%d",ax->id);
    scanf("%s",ax->name);
    ax->city="Example";
    scanf("%s",ax->phone);
        if (t==NULL)
            *p=ax;
                else{
                /*Insert at the end of the list*/
                    t = *p;
                    ax->next = NULL;
                        while(t->next != NULL)
                            t=t->next;
                    t->next = ax;
                }


/************************* ACCOUNTS ******************************/
    scanf("%d",auxid);
    scanf("%s",auxb);
    scanf("%d",auxt);
    scanf("%lf",auxbal);
                /*Insert at the end of the list*/
                    ax->anext = new account;
                    t = *p;
                    t->anext = (*p)->anext;
                    ax->anext->id = auxid;
                    strcpy(ax->anext->bank,auxb);
                    ax->anext->type = auxt;
                    ax->anext->balance = auxbal;
                    ax->anext->next = NULL;
                        if (t->anext == NULL)
                            (*p)->anext = ax->anext;
                        else while(t->anext->next != NULL)
                            t->anext=t->anext->next;
                    t->anext->next = ax->anext;
}
```

To explain better what's happening let's say we insert 2 clients

**Client A:**
1. ID = 4
2. Name = Frank
3. City = Example
4. Phone = 1111

*Client A also has the following accounts*

Account A:
1. ID = 3333
2. Bank = Exampl
3. Type = 2
4. Balance = 35.3

Account B:
1. ID = 4444
2. Bank = Exam
3. Type = 1
4. Balance = 38.3

**Client B:**
1. ID = 6
2. Name = Riley
3. City = Example
4. Phone = 2222

*Client B also has the following accounts*

Account A:
1. ID = 6666
2. Bank = Ex
3. Type = 2
4. Balance = 77.3

Account B:
1. ID = 8888
2. Bank = E
3. Type = 1
4. Balance = 7542.3

Account C:
1. ID = 9998
2. Bank = Ex
3. Type = 2
4. Balance = 752.63

When I finish inserting in the linked list the account list for **Client A** looks like this:

Account B -> Account B -> Account B -> Account B (...) nonstop. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using a mixture of C++ and C in the code with `new` and `scanf` You can use malloc as shown in the example below
2. In the structure declarations, the code given will not compile. `trans *next;` should be changed to `struct trans *next;`. Similarly  `acct *next;` to be changed to `struct  acct *next;`
3. In the client case, you should set `ax->next = NULL` for the case `(t == NULL)` also
4. For inserting the account, I have modified the code by making use of the `ax` variable in the client case as below.

   ```
   account * acc = malloc (sizeof (account));
   account * acc2;
   if (acc == NULL)  {  exit (1); } // or any other method to handle memory error

   scanf("%d",acc->code);
   scanf("%s",acc->bank);
   scanf("%d",acc->type);
   scanf("%lf",acc->balance);        

   acc->next = NULL;

   if (ax->anext == NULL) 
   {
       ax->anext = acc;
   }
   else
   {
       acc2 = ax->anext;
       while (acc2->next != NULL)
       {
           acc2 = acc2->next;
       }
       acc2->next = acc;
   }
   ```